# Can I have a user database synced with SugarCRM and use it mostly for emailing?

Tags: php, email, rest, soap, sugarcrm

I work for a company that has a website with about 700,000 users, it would need a tool that would:

- List all users
- Email users, create templates, send a newsletter
- Show products a user has purchased
- If you find a user, show which emails have been sent to the user
- Create automated tasks, example: send an email to every user that has a product expiring in 30 days

I'm not sure a CRM can do all theses things, I wanted to try a CRM to figure out how close can I get to having a tool that can do all this. I read that SugarCRM is pretty good, and its free so I'm going to try it out.

What I wanted to know is, using the REST or SOAP api of SugarCRM, can I synchronise all my users with the SugarCRM database ? Or for example each time a user is created on our website, insert it in the database.
And then each time we send an email with our website, use SugarCRM instead to send a mail, and store the data. So that we can view which emails have been sent to specific users.

Thank you

Comment: did you read the api documentation to check if the answer you are looking is there? http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/5.5/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_5.5-Chapter%202%20Application%20Framework.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add custom fields to the Contacts module using Studio. The easiest and quickest way to get your data in will be directly to the database.

The standard fields in Sugar Contacts go in the contacts table. Your custom fields will have "_c" appended to their names and be created in the contacts_cstm table. The two tables are related by contacts.id = contacts_cstm.id_c, which is generally a GUID field (but can be any string value if you need it to be).

Then you need to have a process to add new users in your website into sugar. I suggest polling your user db periodically to look for new records and using the SOAP/REST API (good luck though, it's fairly horrible) to insert them into Sugar.

Other than that your use case is pretty much standard Sugar. For automated tasks which happen whenever an email is sent/received or when a new contact is created, you'll want to look at logic hooks, search for logic_hooks.php in the Sugar documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do all that but it may require some customisation to suit it exactly to your needs. By 'users' I assume you are referring to Customer 'Accounts' as known on the SugarCRM?

Comment: Yes I am :). Or "Contacts" don't know exactly yet which is better.

Comment: Importing data into SugarCRM is simple, two methods I have used are  the import facility built within the CRM itself or you can populate the data directly to the database. The table naming convention used makes it easy to understand the database structure.

Good Luck